# how to disable LibreOffice Impress to use multiple display?

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice

I have my Ubuntu Desktop configured on with Dual Monitor. On it Whenever I launch a LibreOffice Impress, it uses both screens, one for current slide and next slide and another for actual presentation.

What I want is to use only one monitor which shows presentation. I dont want the screen with Current slide and Next slide so that it can be used for other purposes.

How should I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to disable the presenter console:

1. Go to **Tools** > **Options**;
2. Then choose **Open Office Impress** > **General** in the left menu;
3. Then under the **Start Presentation** section on the right side;
4. uncheck the box with **Presenter Screen**.

Comment: For me in LibreOffice 6.0.7.3, it's **LibreOffice Impress** and **Enable Presenter Console** under **Presentation**.

Comment: It would be neat if this could be accessed/closed from the presenter screen when it pops up.

Comment: To clarify @Andrew 's comment (which is still correct as of version 7.4.1.2 in Oct 2022): you still need to start by going to **Tools** > **Options**, and then **Presentation** is a section on the right side.

Comment: @Colin OMG YES!!!   + to that idea. I can't fathom how that wasn't an option under **Slide Show** > **Slide Show Options** since day 1.